# please rectify error System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is in expression '{!readUser}'

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, class, asset

I need your help, I am a newbie in Salesforce.

Requirement : Based on employee id need to display assets(like laptop mobile,computers provided by organisations to employees) issued to him by employer

created user__C lookup(user) field  on asset

```
<apex:page standardController="Asset" extensions="assetNewExtension">
<apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel id="userDetails">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Asset.User__c}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!readUser}" reRender="userDetails"/>
            </apex:inputField>
            <apex:outputField value="{!asset.Quantity}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!asset.Quantity}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class assetNewExtension {
    public User selectedUser { get; set; }
    public Asset asset { get; set; }

    public assetNewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
     public assetNewExtension()
    {
        Asset = new asset();
        Asset.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        selectedUser = [ Select Id From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
    }

     public pageReference readUser()
    {
        Asset = [ Select  Quantity From asset Where Id =:Asset.User__c];

        return null;
    } 

}
```

complete error :
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!readUser}' in page vfpage: Class.assetNewExtension.readUser: line 17, column 1

Class.assetNewExtension.readUser: line 17, column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your malformed SOQL query in the readUser method - namely, you are trying to retrieve an Asset with Id equal to the Id of the current User.

So instead of query:

```
Asset = [ Select  Quantity From asset Where Id =:Asset.User__c];
```

...try to use the following:

```
Asset = [SELECT Quantity FROM Asset WHERE User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

---

Oh, and try to consider naming members and variables slightly different than the name of the object. That way it would be much easier to clearly distinct object name from variable name. For instance, in your constructor and readUser method, I initially thought you forgot to declare a variable.

```
public with sharing class assetNewExtension {
    public User selectedUser { get; set; }
    public Asset selectedAsset { get; set; }

    //...constructor(s)...

    public pageReference readUser()
    {
        selectedAsset = [SELECT Quantity FROM Asset WHERE User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It worked correctly ,Thank you dino ursic , Mukesh verma ,  you people helped me alot .

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because your code is wrong constructor. It should be :

```
    public assetNewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

            Asset = new asset();
            Asset.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
            selectedUser = [ Select Id From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
        }
 public pageReference readUser()
    {
        Asset = [ Select  Quantity From asset Where user__c =:Asset.User__c];

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh verma ,thanks for responding , i tried as you said but this is error i got , System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Error is in expression '{!readUser}' in page vfpage: Class.assetNewExtension.readUser: line 17, column 1

Class.assetNewExtension.readUser: line 17, column 1    ---------                               Is there is any document to deal with errors ,plz share

Comment: See revised Answer. SOQL should be of form Select  Quantity From asset Where user__c =:Asset.User__c.

Answer (score 0):

posting completed page & controller

```
       <apex:outputField value="{!selectedAsset.quantity}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!selectedAsset.Name}"/>
       <apex:outputField value="{!selectedAsset.SerialNumber}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

public with sharing class assetNewExtension {
    public User selectedUser { get; set; }
    public Asset selectedAsset { get; set; }
    public Asset Asset { get; set; }

public assetNewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

```
}
 public assetNewExtension()
{
    Asset = new asset();
    Asset.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    selectedUser = [ Select Id From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
}
public pageReference readUser()
{
    selectedAsset = [SELECT Quantity ,Name,SerialNumber FROM Asset WHERE User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you intending to post this as an answer? As you have already had the question answered and accepted one of the answers this is not really necessary. Please see [answer].